# Edit IDA signal handler

Tags: ida, linux, gdb

In Ida Pro while debugging linux process with gdbserver I got window that show than SIGTRAP has been arrived, I choose to pass it to application.

How can I edit that choose now? I want to ignore this signal and not pass it to application

By the way,what signals are causing the process to die in linux  ,so I will choose to not pass them to application?

Answer (score 1):

Debugger > Debugger Options..., [Edit Exceptions](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1414.shtml).